# Помогите сделать правильно парсер

Tags: php, парсер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне необходимо реализовать аналогично, только для харькова.
Как правильно указать границы, чтобы взять нужные данные из текста?
К примеру мне нужно взять данные между "Восход -" и тегом `</div>`

```
$content = "https://www.gismeteo.ua/weather-kharkiv-5053/";

$ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $content);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $body= curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

        $c = preg_match("/Восход/", $body,$a);
        echo $a[0];
```

Comment: почитайте про simple  html dom

Answer (score 0):

```
function Parse($p1, $p2, $p3) {
$num1 = strpos($p1, $p2);
if ($num1 === false) return 0;
$num2 = substr($p1, $num1);
return strip_tags(substr($num2, 0, strpos($num2, $p3)));
```

}

$String = file_get_contents('https://www.gismeteo.ua/weather-kharkiv-5053/');
echo Parse($String, 'Восход', '');

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]